# What does "abstraction" mean in this particular context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, definition

**"A theory aspires to some degree of generality and abstraction."** The book where I found this sentence is a book in one of the disciplines of humanities. According to Merriam-Webster, **"abstraction"** means:

> *1a: the act or process of abstracting : the state of being abstracted* 
> *1b: an abstract idea or term* 
> *2: absence of mind or preoccupation* 
> *3: abstract quality or character* 
> *4a: an abstract composition or creation in art* 
> *4b: ABSTRACTIONISM*

I have absolutely no idea what to make of **"abstraction"** here. Please help me select the correct meaning from the above list so that I can correctly understand what the author is trying to say. Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the process of abstracting

But you probably need now to look up to meaning abstract as a verb, which is related to the meaning as an adjective:

> If a statement, argument, or discussion is abstract, it is general and not based on particular examples. (cambridge)

So a theory needs to some degree to be about general ideas, not only descriptive of particular examples.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Then, thank you. :)

Comment: then why did the author use "generality" in the same sentence?

Comment: It is arguably somewhat redundant, but some redundancy is normal and useful

Comment: Ok, thank you sir. :)

Comment: @adieng Generality means widely applicable. Abstraction means explained in general terms.

Comment: @StephenS Thank you so much, sir.